# Sentiment analysis model return identical output for any input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sentiment-analysis, streamlit

So I made this sentiment analysis model, and it works just fine in the training-testing script. I built a simple interface using streamlit for my saved model, but it always returned identical scores for any input text. Plus, it somehow returns so many scores when it should only return a single score for a single input.

here is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np
import pickle

with open("tokenizer.pkl", "rb") as f:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(f)

@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def load_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('C:/Users/k/Downloads/test/model_final.h5')
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':

    model =  load_model()
    st.title('Analisis Sentimen')

    txt = st.text_input('masukkan teks')

    if not txt:
        st.warning("masukkan teks sebelum lanjut")
        st.stop()
    else:
        text = txt
        text = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
        text = pad_sequences(text)
        prediction = model.predict(text)
        st.title('sentimen: ')
        if (prediction > 0.5).any():
            st.write(prediction)
            st.write('positif')
        else:
            st.write(prediction)
            st.write('negatif')
```

here are some snaps when i try it with streamlit
[image]

[image]

Comment: To test the code you need to provide the model in some way. The problem may be in the way you trained the model. Is it possible to test your code using a similar pre-trained model taken from some website? If the problem persists even with that, then we investigate this code.

Comment: @GiuseppeLaGualano Thanks for the response. Actually, I don't mind sharing it if it helps, Here is the code for the model I'm using:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gCRclCOlLi_1u4RkzaUwp4iqq28TwMZE

Answer (score 0):

ML is almost all trial and error. I modified the model like below, and got good results. Kindly try changing the model.

```
model = Sequential()

embedding_size = 50

model.add(Embedding(input_dim=1500,output_dim=embedding_size,input_length=max_tokens,name='embedding_layer'))
model.add(LSTM(16,))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(16,))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

optimizer = Adam()

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Please find the working code [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/16e311aed94e5ca6ea531307d06a01d0/project14_final.ipynb#scrollTo=8lxWX4jyYl8h). Thank you!